# POST Error vs PUT Error: Are they the same thing?

Tags: http

Im getting an error calling a REST controller.

If I use POST I get `404 Not Found`

If I use PUT I get `gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

From what I understand, these seem to be the same error for different calls.

could these be the same errors under different names or does it usually indicate that the PUT is managing to get further before erroring (else would have returned 404?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error is from your local system, telling you that it couldn't convert a hostname to an IP address. There are two possible causes for that:

One is that DNS for the remote HTTP host went away between the two calls, and your local system had no cache of that.

The other is that your second URL has a tyop in it, and the hostname isn't valid.

From my experience, the second is my usual failure mode.

(the `gai` set of functions are the modern way to turn a hostname into a set of addresses, which is how I identified the probably root cause.)